# Modifying EJS tag onclick -- Adding an input to a form onclick

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, ejs

I've been self-teaching coding for the last 3 months or so and I have a couple of issues with a page I'm trying to make. I think my problems are a bit basic so I'm a little ashamed to ask. Any guidance would be very useful. Thank you!

I have a page that accepts recipes. Each recipe has a set number of instructions or ingredients.
The form that accepts the new recipe by default shows 3 fields to add instructions and 3 fields to add ingredients.

I'd like to implement a button that allows the user to add an extra ingredient or an extra step to the instructions.

This is what the New view file looks like in the instruction segment. It's pretty much the same for ingredients give or take a few things.

```
<div class="mb-3">
     <label class="form-label" for="instructions" id="labelInstructions">instructions</label>
        
     <% for(let i = 0; i<3; i++){ %>
     <div class="input-group" id="instructionGroup">
     <div class="input-group-prepend">
       <span class="input-group-text">Step <%= i+1 %> </span>
     </div>
      <textarea class="form-control" aria-label=<%=`Instructions-Step-${i +1}`%> name=<%=`recipe[instructions][${i}][body]` %> id="instructions"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="valid-feedback">Looks good!</div>
     
     <% } %>
```

I tried adding an onclick function to a

```
        <button onclick="addInstruction()">+</button>
```

I required the file on the template and the file attempted to add the appropriate amount of divs and modify the classes and innertext, etc, etc.

But I got stuck here:

```
function addInstruction() {
    console.log('clicked')
    const label = document.getElementById('labelInstructions')
    const tempDiv = document.createElement('div')
    label.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", tempDiv)
}
```

In the console it shows that it is being clicked but it doesn't add the div I created. I know the rest of the logic isn't there yet I just wanted to see if I could see the div first, but I can't see anything.

Then I started thinking it would be easier to just add one to the loop limit. But that loop is written inside an EJS tag, I was wondering if there was a way to modify that through an onclick event. Or if there's just an entirely better way of doing this that I'm missing.

I'm very new to this, any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking how to add some sort of div inside the DOM when a user clicks a button. To do this I would just use the `.appendChild()` method and append the div as a child element of the form for example `document.querySelector("form").appendChild(<Div Variable>)`